# How can I get my ceiling fan/lights to work independently?

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

I purchased a used Harbor Breeze ceiling fan used because it was a nice looking fan, but am stymied on if it is possible to wire it for independent light and fan use.  The ceiling fan has only two wires and a ground wire coming out while most ceiling fan units with lights have 3.  I have two switches and can use only one but it turns on both the light and the fan at the same time and there is no pull cords to control the unit externally.

I purchased a universal remote controller that covers the Harbor Breeze brand but it has 3 wires to attach to the ceiling fan and the fan has only two.  I looked down the wire tube to see if the 3rd wire slipped down there and their was a wire but it had a hard factory nipple on it like antenna's do so I assume the controller is built into the base unit.  I can get the light housing off, it is attached to two wires but I do not see any screws or bolts to disassemble the main housing.  Called Harbor Breeze but they say the MFG. went out of business and they have no remotes that will pair with this fan. Any ideas? am I out of luck? I really like the fan because it has beautiful real wood blades, that I stupidly took the time to refinish as it powered on and I assumed I could get a remote.

Harbor Breeze
Model #60-STG
Item #0464472

[fan wiring](https://photos.app.goo.gl/LFN84eYnpEwcqHdTA)

https://photos.app.goo.gl/ySCoPqCF9dFNAgey7

Black and white wire from ceiling exit to 9 pin. Blue - light wire connects to black wire from grey box. red wire exits from box and connects to 9pin exiting as black towards motor area ( I assume power to fan). This gives me my third wire so that is good the only question is 3 smaller gauge wires brown, grey and light blue that come from the controller through the 9 pin and down into the motor area? Must control the 3 speeds to the fan? any chance that functionality is now built into the universal remote controller I have? If not I guess there is no fix.
Additionally I put the bulb in my candelabra and it worked fine, dimmed and all so I assume it is house power and not stepped down.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Please [edit] to include the brand/model of the "universal" remote, and maybe even a link to its install instructions.

Comment: There might be a way with a smart light, but need someone who knows if they will work.  Any old fashion work arounds will need work and modification of the fan.  I kind of remember a pull switch that screws into the light socket.

Comment: Various companies (sold at most big box and hardware stores) make a receiver that goes in the fan unit, and wall mounted (and hand held) transmitters to send commands to the receiver. I've used them, they work just fine.

Comment: A bit of googling showed this to be a "Harbor Breeze" fan. Probably conflated with "Hampton Bay". You may have contacted the wrong company for the replacement remote.

Answer (score 1):

Per the instructions for the [Harbor Breeze Model # 60-STG](https://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/836071008863_install.pdf) there is no separate connection for the light:

Wiring the fan to power has only black, white, ground, with no separate wires for light and fan:

[image: Harbor Breeze fan power wiring]

The light kit is wired up with two connectors between the motor body and light kit:

[image: Harbor Breeze fan light kit]

There is no indication that there is a manufacturer-approved way to wire the light separately, since the fan includes a remote control system in the motor body which separately controls the light and fan.

If the bulbs are normal bulbs that can go in any compatible light socket in a lamp or light fixture, they probably run on full house power through the fan controller. You might be able to pass another wire down through the shaft in the middle of the fan body. Disconnect the light kit's black wire from the blue wire on the fan body, and connect it to your new wire, with proper wire nut technique. Then wire the new wire to your new remote's Light control wire. Note that this is not using the fan according to directions, though. This may cause trouble with insurance if there is a fire.

If the bulbs are special, working only with this fan, the power may not be house power, and you shouldn't try to wire them separately.

Another problem you may have is that the new remote controller will be feeding power to the built-in remote controller, not directly to the fan motor, which may not work correctly when you try to run the fan on lower speeds with the new controller. Digging out the old controller would be necessary, which would really be not using the fan according to directions and really cause insurance trouble incase of a fire.

FWIW the Harbor Breeze fan is a Lowes product, so Lowe's may have an ability to get a new remote. There is a customer service number on the cover of the instruction manual PDF.

Comment: I tried to lay out the wiring here but too many words, still learning to use this site and can't figure out how to add pictures. The bulb fits and works in my candelabra so house powered. Appreciate your good answer and will try and update my question if I can find where to do it.

Comment: The new pictures show the wiring all open so you could remove (or at least disconnect) the fan motor and light from the old controller and attach them to the new controller. Exactly which wires to connect would take more study than I could do from the pictures, though.